# Why does assert np.nan == np.nan cause an error?

Tags: python, numpy

If

```
assert 1 == 1
```

is fine, then why does:

```
assert np.nan == np.nan
```

cause an assertion error?

What's even more confusing, this is OK:

```
assert np.nan != np.nan
```

What's the best way to test for `nan`?

Comment: Because `NaN` != `NaN`, it's part of floating point number specification. Test for _identity_ (`is` operator), not _equality_.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NaN` has the property that it doesn't equal itself, you should use [`np.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to test `NaN` values, here `np.isnan(np.nan)` will yield `True`:

```
In[5]:
np.nan == np.nan

Out[5]: False

In[6]:
np.nan != np.nan

Out[6]: True

In[7]:
np.isnan(np.nan)

Out[7]: True
```

Comment: `is` is not a great idea:

    `a = np.float(1e150)/1e-250`
    `b = np.float(-1e150)/1e-250`
    `a+b is np.nan` produces `False`. This is because `np.nan` is an *example* of a NaN, not *the* NaN.

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.isnan(value)`. [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) doesn't compare equal to itself because it indicates a failure, and might not have been produced the same way. I'm not sure why `isnan` is missing in the CPython documentation, but it's present in `math` for both CPython 3.4 and 2.7, and as a ufunc in `numpy`.