# Python unittest assert complex dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to perform the following assertation which fails for some reason:

```
{'a': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 2.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 3.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])],
 'b': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 4.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 5.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])],
 'c': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 6.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 7.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])]} != {'a': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 2.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 3.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])],
 'b': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 4.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 5.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])],
 'c': [('Power',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 6.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)]),
       ('Speed',
        [(datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), 7.0),
         (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 1, 26, 911251), nan)])]}
```

I have tried both `self.assertEqual` and `self.assertDictEqual` but still the same thing happens. I create the datetime once in my test and it is the same one in all examples. Why is this failing? I'm new to testing in Python, so some help would be appreciated.

Here is what I get when I run assertDictEqual:

```
AssertionError: {'a':[1093 chars], (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 30, 14, 965541), nan)])]} != {'a':[1093 chars], (datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 11, 14, 30, 14, 965541), nan)])]}
```

Comment: This isn't quite clear. Those two dictionaries are the same, so `!=` will fail.

Comment: Exactly, but I still get this problem? assert instances == expected_instances fails while assert instances != expected_instances passes. But when I manually compare them string representation is the same...

Comment: `nan` is an object. Maybe its value may be changed at some moment.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this was the problem

```
assert np.NaN == np.NaN
```

This fails. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367557/why-does-assert-np-nan-np-nan-cause-an-error).

Instead, you could use numpy's methods for assertion:

```
from numpy.testing import assert_equal
assert_equal(instances, expected_instances)
```

Works like a charm.