# The numpy where() function is only working once

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
myList = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
arr = np.array(myList, dtype='float')
arr[1,1] = np.nan
arr[1,2] = np.inf
arr = np.where(arr==np.inf, -1, arr)
arr = np.where(arr==np.nan, -1, arr)
print(arr)
```

When I try to replace nan and inf, only the first where function works. If they're switched, nan will work instead of inf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does assert np.nan == np.nan cause an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367557/why-does-assert-np-nan-np-nan-cause-an-error)

Answer (score 2):

You can not check with `== np.nan`, since `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`, indeed:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

You can use the [**`isnan(..)`** function [numpy-doc]](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) for that:

```
arr = np.where(np.isnan(arr), -1, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [np.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) function to check 'nan'ness of a number.

You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367571/2959389) :

'NaN has the property that it doesn't equal itself, you should use np.isnan to test NaN values'

```
import numpy as np
myList = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
arr = np.array(myList, dtype='float')
arr[1,1] = np.nan
arr[1,2] = np.inf
arr = np.where(arr==np.inf, -1, arr)
arr = np.where(np.isnan(arr), -1, arr)
print(arr)
```