# How can I modify apply and lambda function to create new column based on other in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have table like below in Python Pandas with float64 data type:

```
col1
--------
245.121
NaN
44.908
```

And I try to create new column "col2" using below code:

```
data["col2"] = data.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.col1== np.nan else 0, axis = 1)
```

Unfortunately, when I use above code I have 0 everywhere, why ? How can I modyfi my code to achieve something like below:

```
col1      col2
--------
245.121  | 0
NaN      | 1
44.908   | 0
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: Use `np.isnan(x.col1)` or `pd.isnull(x.col1)`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367557/why-does-assert-np-nan-np-nan-cause-an-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data["col2"] = data.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.col1 in [np.nan] else 0, axis = 1)
```

This should work, while yours doesn't because it's [a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true) that `np.nan != np.nan`

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work, hmmm I it impossiblem I do not understand why

Comment: sorry I used df while debugging now it should work

Comment: np.where(df.col1.isin([np.nan]), 1, 0)  <-- it works